# UIDatepicker shows dates in my native language

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

Does anybody know how to make the UIdatepicker dates appear ALWAYS in english. because right now I am in Greece and the dates are appearing in Greek Language. For instance instead of Today it has Σήμερα.

Comment: Is your device's default language set to Greek? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9639991/2274694

Comment: Change the `locale` property of the date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the locale in the date pickers attribute inspector to english

[image]