# Change UIDatePicker calendar/region format in app

Tags: cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

How is it possible to change the language/region format on the UIDatePicker via an in-app option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone:DatePicker dd/mm/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939943/iphonedatepicker-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a picker for choosing from the list of `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]` or some list like this. Then you set the date picker's locale according to the user's selection.

Answer (score 0):

Found What I needed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944352/1827583

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/97760-set-locale-and-calendar-to-uidatepicker.html

I can change the Calendar format to Japanese and the region format to "ja_JP"