# Issue in Uidatepicker Dateformat for assigned region

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I want to set date format in date picker for region "es_us"(Spanish-UnitedStates) in my app .For this i have set locale to date picker "es-US" . When Date picker appears it shows date picker in format "dd/MM/yyyy" but actually date format for locale "es-US" is "MM/dd/yyyy".
how can i set format to dd/MM/yyyy in date picker ? below is my code what i have written .

```
   UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
    datePicker.hidden = YES;
    datePicker.date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-2629743.83*12*25];
    datePicker.locale =  [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_US"];
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There may be issue of NSlocale try this one

```
NSArray* languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *language = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:     [languages objectAtIndex:0]];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:language]];
```

This may help you

Comment: @@arpit:Thanks for suggestion . I have tried above code ,but it sets my date-format but now date picker is in English ,i want it in Spanish.:(

Answer (score 0):

In Apple's documentation they specified that in `UIDatePickerModeDate`. The `DatePicker` displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the `locale` setting. An example of this mode is `[ November | 15 | 2007 ]`. But In device it display as `DD/MM/YYYY`. See `UIDatePicker` for more info.

Although The locale property for UIDatePicker was deprecated from iOS 5.

or you could create your own `UIPickerView` with the values you want.

you can check this answer too..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944352/1865424

and your 2nd issue regarding changing language of `UIDatePicker` ..

The `locale` property (and all other country specific format properties for that matter) defaults to the value returned by `currentLocale`, which in turns depends on the iphone's country settings, not the language settings. You need to set the appropriate country in the iphone general settings.

Courtesy:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265984/1865424