# How to show date picker in US Format(DD/MM/YY)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
  if (_providerDatePicker) _providerDatePicker.hidden =
     !_providerDatePicker.hidden; if (_providerToolbar)
     _providerToolbar.hidden = !_providerToolbar.hidden; float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
     _providerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 244, self. view.bounds.size.width,
     44)];

      UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self
     action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:)];
     _providerToolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
     target:nil action:nil], done];
     _providerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; [self.view addSubview:_providerToolbar];

     _providerDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 200,
     screenWidth, 200.0f)];
     _providerDatePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     _providerDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;    // [_providerDatePicker setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]
     initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"]];

     _providerDatePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

I am using method in button action to show DatePicker but it is Comming but it show like shown in image. I want to change it to DD/MM/YY. Help me in this?[image]

Comment: https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/textFiled_InputView

Comment: @KiritModi Code is in Swift...i need objective c

Comment: @RamanSrivastava You've commented out the call to set the locale, does this not solve your issue?

Comment: US format is normally m/d/y almost everywhere else uses d/m/y https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: @GeorgeGreen no my friend its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want to actually show it in US format. The US format for dates is month/day/year.

If you want English and day/month/year, you can use the British locale:

```
_providerDatePicker.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
```

In general it's not a good idea to tamper with locales to set a specific format. You should be using the system format because that's the one the users want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the answer here:
[iPhone:DatePicker dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939943/iphonedatepicker-dd-mm-yyyy)

```
NSLocale *uk = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setLocale:uk];
[myDatePicker setCalendar:cal];
```